# Can I clear any pending users' alerts emails

Tags: 2013, administration, alert, smtp, outgoing-email

I am working on a sharepoint farm 2013. and i wanted to arrange the documents inside our document libraries, by creating additional libraries, create folders, remove duplicate documents, etc..

and during this period i disable user alerts by defining "1234" inside the Outbound SMTP server, as follow:-

[image]

now i finished my work, and i want to define back the real "Outbound SMTP server".. but i am afraid that some users might have defined to get user alerts on daily basis or on weekly basis , and as a result they might receive many users' alerts emails. so my question is; If there is a way inside sharepoint to clear any pending user alerts' emails?

Answer (score 0):

Reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-view-or-delete-sharepoint-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2)

1- Click Settings  SharePoint 2016 Settings button on title bar. or Site Actions  Button image , and then click Site Settings.

2- Under Site Administration, click User alerts.

3- Click Display alerts for to select a user, and then click Update.

4- Select the checkbox next to the alert you want to delete, and then click Delete Selected Alerts.

5- Click OK.

Comment: i do not want to delete the actual users alerts themselves.. i just want to clear any pending emails that might be sent if i return back the correct value inside the "Outbound SMTP server".. i hope this clarify my question..

Answer (score 0):

Check Immediate alerts timer job status. Cancel the scheduled jobs is any.